# Extract a particular json field [ ] from json string and store in HashMap using Mulesoft or Java

Tags: java, json, hashmap, azure-ad-graph-api

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('c-480b-9f29-27b4de54c85b')/drive/items('01QZDPV46NIERRXLPDDRHIYT4HGDYL2CZS')/workbook/worksheets('Sheet123')/tables('1')/rows",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.id": "/users('9af3784f-924c-480b-9f29-27b4de54c85b')/drive/items('01QZDPV46NIERRXLPDDRHIYT4HGDYL2CZS')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B77104C57-F2DA-49CE-B55C-9D7D458A%7D%27)/tables(%271%27)/rows/itemAt(index=0)",
            "index": 0,
            "values": [
                [
                    100,
                    "fname1",
                    "lname1",
                    123,
                    "fname1@gmail"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.id": "/users('9a24c-480b-9f29-27b4de54c85b')/drive/items('01QZDPVYT4HGDYL2CZS')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B77104C57-F2DA-49CED458A%7D%27)/tables(%271%27)/rows/itemAt(index=1)",
            "index": 1,
            "values": [
                [
                    102,
                    "fname2",
                    "lname2",
                    345,
                    "fname2@gmail.com"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

1. I am accessing the rows of an excel from sharepoint using
   Microsoft graph api and doing so i am getting the above response.
2. I am trying to remove the unnecessary part from the above json like
    "@odata.id" field its value, field "index":its value and extract the
    field "values": [] from json string and store in HashMap of type Employee 
    using mulesoft  or java.

Comment: I think it would help if your JSON data ... would be A) smaller, but B) followed by an example that shows which data exactly you want to fetch from that JSON dump. Because I have *no* idea which fields represent *emp* details ...

Comment: I am trying to extract the "values": [
                [
                    102,
                    "fname2",
                    "lname2",
                    345,
                    "fname2@gmail.com"
                ]: inside the json response.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to extract the "values": [ [ 102, "fname2", "lname2", 345, "fname2@gmail.com" ]: inside the json response.

The [JSON-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library is easy to use.

```
import org.json.*;
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
Object values = obj.getJSONArray("value").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("values");
```